# Allow md-error to show the error message even if control is untouched

Tags: angular, angular-material2

With the release of [Material 2.0.0-beta.3](https://github.com/angular/material2/releases/tag/2.0.0-beta.3) came the new `md-error` directive for displaying error messages ([#3560](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3560)).
`md-error` seems however to only show the error message if the control is `touched` and `invalid`. This is probably a good default setting, but in some scenarios, I want to be able to customize when an error is shown. Can I customize under which conditions the error message is shown?

In the Angular documentation under [Show and hide validation error messages](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html#!#show-and-hide-validation-error-messages) they mention that

> You control visibility of the name error message by binding properties of the name control to the message  element's hidden property

and explain that a valid choice could be: `[hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine"` (which is not dependent on `touched`). I want to accomplish the same thing but using Material instead of Boostrap that is used in the documentation.

Please see my [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/kBxsOfoxlwdLfm5ObWtD?p=preview) for a live sample where I have two input controls. Each require at least 2 characters. I want the error to be shown directly after the user has typed the first character. The first input control uses `md-error` but I am unable to get the desired behavior.
The second input control uses and older workaround with `md-hint` where one could accomplish this by using `*ngIf`:

```
<md-hint *ngIf="fc2.dirty && fc2.invalid">
  Name must be at least 2 characters.
</md-hint>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to customize when the md-error should be visible. Therefore, I have submitted this as a [feature request](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4232).

If all you want to change is that the error should be shown directly when the control gets dirty, @HopScotch47 gave a good workaround on GitHub to set the control as touched in the constructor:

```
const ctrl = this.form.controls['ctrlName'];
ctrl.markAsTouched();
```